# Why is the file size of an app update greater than or equal to a new download in Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Today I updated my app on the Google Play Store, I'm using Unity3d. The changes I make to the .apk are only 3 or 5 mb. but when a player updates, the file size for the updated app is the same size or greater as a for a player who is freshly installing the game.

Why are the updates greater than or equal to the app size?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you push a new release, it is an update for your current users, but it is fresh installing package for your new users. Google Play will handle the updating or installing phase for you. Your users don't have any choice of what they want in Google Play.

**Edit** (to make things clearer):
Google uses (or at least until now) `Delta updates` (or what they call `Smart updates`) to update apps on Google Play.

> This has been implemented in Google's Android operating system devices
>   that run on Android 2.3 or above. Google engineers have estimated that
>   smart updates would be only about one third the size of a full update
>   on average.

And they began to use it from 2012:

> Google Play has used delta algorithms since 2012, and we recently
>   rolled out an additional delta algorithm, [bsdiff (created by Colin
>   Percival)](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/), that our experimentation shows can reduce delta size by up
>   to 50% or more compared to the previous algorithm for some APKs.
>   Bsdiff is specifically targeted to produce more efficient deltas of
>   native libraries by taking advantage of the specific ways in which
>   compiled native code changes between versions. To be most effective,
>   native libraries should be stored uncompressed (compression interferes
>   with delta algorithms).

So don't worry, your users don't need to download the whole app again if you only change some code in your new version of apps. But if you change the whole code in your apps, of course they will have to download the whole app again because it is fresh new now. If you don't want the updates being handled by Google, you can do this process in your server side.

**Sources:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_update

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/07/improvements-for-smaller-app-downloads.html

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sir, you did'nt understand what i'm saying. I'm saying, my current users are still download whole game again, even my update is 3 or 5 mb. Current users are download all 40mb (all apk size) again but i just want to, they download only changes (change size) not all game again... why is that happening? why all my users have to download all size again, again again...

Comment: No, your users don't have to download the whole apk again. Let me edit my answer to make it clearer for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused by the way Google Play displays data size for the app in the download activity vs. the update activity. Understandably so, as they provide no context as to whether or not the file size listed is just the update, or the entire app size.

The answer is, it depends.

@Silver gave a great explanation of how their updated algorithm handles the downloading of data but I think your confusion is on the perceived file size that is displayed on the different Play activities.

Depending on what was changed, a smaller or larger portion of the entire application may need to be re-downloaded. For example, if you made a change to a list of `enums`, or added a `strings.xml` file for a different language, you might expect this to be a very small update. But throughout your program, files have been updated to handle the new change. Depending on where in the hierarchy of your program these changes occur, a user may have a larger download than expected.

For major releases (i.e. `AppVersion-MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`) the user may have to re-download the entire app as so many of the base libraries have changed.

> **Size-on-Disk Tip:** Utilize a hosted API whenever possible and practical to do so in order to outsource processing power and file size to the API instead of running it all locally on the user's device. While you will have to use data (Wi-Fi or otherwise) to make the API calls; concise JSON does not require much data.